# navigating internet page

Tags: testing

I want to write code to log onto an Internet account and also click buttons to navigate to do different things such as watch for something to change. for example I would like

- log on to account
- click to navigate
  while(until I say to stop)
- watch for changes

Comment: Do you need this for testing or in order to brute force a login form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may look at 
http://watij.com/

Answer (score 0):

For automated website tests you can use [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You might not need to write code - if you use FireFox, perhaps try the [iMacros addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/imacros-for-firefox/)?

Answer (score 0):

You've not said what language you want to write this in -- for .NET there's http://watin.org/

Comment: sorry i am trying to do this in java..but if there is a better way let me know